# redux toolkit with preact : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, preact

I am trying to setup redux toolkit (RTK) query with preact (https://preactjs.com/)

The setup works however when I am trying to use the API call as hook from the slice, I am getting below error

Error :

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

[image]

The above error is thrown by the call to useGetUsersQuery() when I am trying to use the hook.

```
export function Content() {
  const { data } = useGetUsersQuery();
  return (
    <div>Users</div>
  );
}
```

Redux Version (preact/compat is being used to support react-redux):

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.2",
"react-redux": "8.0.5"
```

store.ts

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [userSlice.reducerPath]: userSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userSlice.middleware),
});

export default store;
```

userSlice.ts

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
export const userSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query<User[], void>({
      query: () => "users",
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUsersQuery } =userSlice;
```

index.ts

```
<Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue .

Answer (score 0):

It seems very weird that you are using the UMD build here - nowadays most bundlers should access the ESM, or at least CommonJS builds. Maybe you are stuck on outdated tooling?

As far as I know, that UMD build will try to access `window.React.useContext` - and in your case `window.React` is probably not set, as you are using preact.

Comment: thanks for the response .. I ended up using react query instead ..